# Duplicate content generated(uuids, cached responses) javascript

Tags: javascript, web

For an ecommerce website we are building data registration object. For this we need te create uuid's of websessions. While building we seeme to generate a lot of duplicates. 
As a small test we build a small piece of code. This code however still gives a lot of duplicates.

```
        <script>
        (function () {
            var urlEndpoint = 'https://<url>/<endpoint>';
            var createXmlHttpRequest = function (url, settings) {
                var request = ('XMLHttpRequest' in window) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP'); // eslint-disable-line no-undef
                request.open('POST', url);
                request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                request.send((settings.data || ''));
                request.onload = function () {
                    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 300 && typeof settings.callback === 'function') {
                        settings.callback('uuid=' + JSON.parse(request.response).uuid + '&timestamp=' + JSON.parse(request.response).timestamp);
                    }
                }
            };
            createXmlHttpRequest(urlEndpoint + '?getuuid=1&' + (new Date()).getTime(), {
                callback: function (data) {
                    createXmlHttpRequest(urlEndpoint + '?' + (new Date()).getTime(), {data: data})
                }
            })
        })();
    </script>
```

what we do is:
- get a uuid from a backend script trough a post
- pass that uuid back to another backend script and save it in a database

when doing this, we get al lot of duplicates in the second backend call. This does not make any sense to me, but maybe someone can shed a light and help us out.

This is by the way a high trafiic website with more then 2M view a day.

Also: the second call to save the uuid is for testing purposes. This will be removed and we will be using the uuid in the frontend

Comment: Wouldn't this be an issue with the code generating the UUID on the server?

Comment: Hi, no these are definitly unique. that is why we also return the timestamp. this is also duplicate

Comment: The question is, you are either receiving duplicates, or are sending multiple requests with the same UUID... Why do you need one call to create the ID and another to save it? Can't it be done in one go???

Comment: This is just a test setup. the second call will be removed and the uuid will be used in the frontend only

Comment: First test that your backend uuid generator is returning unique values. Use console.log or similar. Also, just a comment on code structure, it's confusing to reuse the `createXmlHttpRequest` function for two rather different purposes, and having it pass a callback that again invokes the same function but causes different behavior based on presence of a callback. I have to look back and forth between them 3 times to undersntad the flow. Try defining two separate functions - one for the initial request, one for the callback behavior, and name them more clearly based on their purpose.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, my backend uuid generator is 100% delivering unique values. So the issue is not there. We believe it has to do with weird browser javascript engines, or maybe bots. but we cannot reproduce it. We hope the community can help us.